# How to turn a given String into a Array?

Tags: java

Given a String, say `String s = "abcderfh"`;

How would you turn this into a String Array.

Thank you in Advance.....

Comment: I guess that you mean a "char" array instead of a String array since you give an example with a single word.

Comment: unless he want's a string array.  I know it sounds crazy...

Comment: A String array containing what? The individual characters? An array with just one element, that string? Something else?

Comment: Yeah definitely, Jeetesh, could you precise what you meant?

Comment: @Laurence : An array of string objects that contain single letters.  A single letter can be a string.

Comment: @StefanH anyway that would be cumbersome, what would be the purpose of it? Perhaps executing methods that are only available for Strings ...

Comment: @lc2817 - u were right, char Array is needed....

Comment: @lc2817: Exactly.  I try not to pretend to know what the OP is asking.  Occasionally people do ask the question they intend to ask.  But the OP should clarify, since it is not perfectly clear what they want.

Comment: @Jeetesh: You can get your answer by simple googling.. put efforts from your side dude. Its a common thing that you want to do.

Comment: @StefanH Perhaps I should have been more clear that I was asking the OP for clarification...

Comment: @StefanH you are right, I didn't mean that what you were doing was wrong!

Comment: @JeeteshNataraj If I was right, why did you mark the "String array solution" as the answer? What would we thr purpose to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean an array of String, where each element is one letter, do this:

```
String s = "abcderfh";
String[] letters = s.split("(?<=.)"); // split after every character
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letters));
```

Output:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, r, f, h]
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a valid answer given the vague question.

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to obtain an array of characters, you should use the toCharArray() method on the String.

So you can do this:

```
String s = "abcderfh";
char[] myarray = s.toCharArray()
```

Answer (score -2):

You can find a great example right here:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/

Comment: It is not at all about JQuery, it is a Java question.